# log4j:ERROR while writing the logs statements in file

Tags: java, log4j

I have created a java project called Project1. for this project i created a log4j.properties file. For writing the log statements in log file, i used DailyRollingFileAppenders. I am using log4j-1.2.16.jar. The log file is :

```
log4j.logger.com.gridsense.server.automode=DEBUG, stdout,Rollfile
log4j.rootLogger=off
log4j.logger.com.gridsense.server.automode=debug,Rollfile,stdout

log4j.appender.Rollfile=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.Rollfile.ImmediateFlush=false
log4j.appender.Rollfile.Append=true
log4j.appender.Rollfile.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.Rollfile.bufferedIO = true
log4j.appender.Rollfile.File=D:/logs/AutoGS.log
log4j.appender.Rollfile.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.Rollfile.layout.ConversionPattern=[%t] %-5p %c %d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}     %m%n

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Threshold=DEBUG
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x  %m%n
```

When i run the project i get the following error

```
log4j:ERROR Could not close org.apache.log4j.helpers.QuietWriter@1105348
java.io.IOException: The handle is invalid
at java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.write(FileOutputStream.java:282)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(StreamEncoder.java:202)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implWrite(StreamEncoder.java:263)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.write(StreamEncoder.java:106)
at java.io.OutputStreamWriter.write(OutputStreamWriter.java:190)
at java.io.BufferedWriter.flushBuffer(BufferedWriter.java:111)
at java.io.BufferedWriter.close(BufferedWriter.java:246)
at java.io.FilterWriter.close(FilterWriter.java:87)
at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.closeFile(FileAppender.java:185)
at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.reset(FileAppender.java:343)
at org.apache.log4j.WriterAppender.close(WriterAppender.java:207)
at org.apache.log4j.AppenderSkeleton.finalize(AppenderSkeleton.java:144)
at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.invokeFinalizeMethod(Native Method)
at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.runFinalizer(Finalizer.java:83)
at java.lang.ref.Finalizer.access$100(Finalizer.java:14)
at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:160)
    log4j:ERROR Failed to write [[DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2] DEBUG   com.gridsense.server.automode.backgroundWorker.TimerTaskToBeFired 03/05/2013 17:34:45 ? TimerTaskToBeFired.execute - firing timer job with Key [DropBoxFileFetchingSchedulerGroup.JobDetail-ID-1]].
```

I don't understand what is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My reading of the stacktrace is that something has *leaked* a FileAppender object, and that appender's `finalize` method is attempting to clean it up.  But it looks like that is failing because the resource in question has already been closed.

That's the easy part.  The hard part is identifying the source of the leak.  My guess is that it is caused by this line:

```
    log4j.logger.com.gridsense.server.automode=debug,Rollfile,stdout
```

which appears to be configuring a second logger tree duplicating the one configure a couple of lines earlier.

Comment: i modified my code and delete second statement log4j.logger.com.gridsense.server.automode=debug,Rollfile,stdout    still i get the same error.